# Why should I declare <mvc:resources> in my configuration file

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm having hard time understanding the purpose of `<mvc:resources mapping="..." location=".."/>`section in my configuration file.

my project structure...

```
--WebContent    
-----META-INF    
-----static    
-----------images    
------------js    
------------css    
-----WEB-INF    
--------jsps    
--------spring-configs    

--------web.xml
```

I'm able to access files under images, js and css folders even when I don't specify this section in the spring servlet config file. So why do I need to specify this? What purpose does it serve exactly?

For the record, this is what I have in my config file.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need it if that's where you put your resources. Everything at the root of your web application (WebContent), which isn't `WEB-INF` or `META-INF` is publicly available and the Servlet container can serve it to any client.

The `<mvc:resources ... />` element is meant to serve resources which are within `WEB-INF` which is not available directly to clients. They must be served by your application.

Comment: thank you.. most of the examples out there on the web place these files outside of the WEB-INF folder. I never thought of this angle.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what `@Sotirios` has answered, `<mvc:resources/>` can resolve static resources from Classpath resources ( for e.g., a jar file). This opens up the possibility of packaging your static resources in a self-contained jar module along with your business logic (although very few people use this approach in command based framework like Spring  -  this is more prevalent in Component based frameworks like JSF).
Apart from this there are other benefits of using this tag as mentioned [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html). I'm quoting

> The cache-period property may be used to set far future expiration
>   headers (1 year is the recommendation of optimization tools such as
>   Page Speed and YSlow) so that they will be more efficiently utilized
>   by the client. The handler also properly evaluates the Last-Modified
>   header (if present) so that a 304 status code will be returned as
>   appropriate, avoiding unnecessary overhead for resources that are
>   already cached by the client